# Rename [kopiluwak] and [weaselcoffee] to hyphenate their names

Tags: support, tags

We have two mainsite tags thanks to [this question on kopi luwak](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/139/47): [kopiluwak](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kopiluwak) and [weaselcoffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weaselcoffee)

Tag convention is to hyphenate spaces in a name, not skip them, so these tags should be: [kopi-luwak](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kopi-luwak) and [weasel-coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weasel-coffee). The latter should probably be a synonym, since we don't need two tags for the same coffee.

Could a moderator replace these tags?

Answer (score 2):

Just checking, we're keeping *luwak* and not *alamid* (as it's known in most of the rest of SE Asia?) I'm fine with that, as luwak is how it's been made famous, I just want to make sure before I go doing tag surgery :)

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion myself - I first heard of that coffee through the question about it! But whatever tag we use it should be hyphenated if it has a space. ;)

Comment: I think *luwak* should have historical precedence (as the coffee originated with the Indonesian plantations), but maybe a synonym is useful.